VBA - Outlook - display inbox of work personnal and inbox of shared mailbox
I have multiples account synced on my outlook desktop app and I am looking for code to display only 2 inbox.
I am aware of the "unified method" but I tried to filter this depending on folder or mailboxes and couldnt make it to work
' This macro creates a "unified inbox" - a search across all inboxes and sent items.
' Steps to use it:
' 1. Enable developer tab to see VBA console:
'    Options > Customize Ribbon > 
'    Enable the selection field before “Developer” and OK.
' 2. Add macro:
'    From the Developer tab open Visual Basic dialog
'    Open VBA Add the Sub below to General context
' 3. Enable macros: 
'    Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings
'    Choose 'Notifications for all macros' and OK.
' 4. Add the macro to Quick Access Toolbar:
'    Options > Quick Access Toolbar
'    Choose commands from 'Macros'
'    Select the macro 'Project1.ThisOutllokSession.UnifiedInbox' and [add] it to the right side pane.
'    Select [Modify] and choose an icon and display name. and OK.
Sub UnifiedInbox()
  Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
  Dim tDate As Date
  tDate = Date - 14 '7 days ago
  txtSearch = "folder:Inbox received:(>" & tDate & ")" & " OR folder:Sent sent:(>" & tDate & ")"
  myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeCurrentFolder
  myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders
  Set myOlApp = Nothing
End Sub


See Advanced Search Scope set to multiple mailboxes and Look through 2 outlook root folders in Excel with VBA.
